# Why doesn't LinkedHashSet always retain order?

Tags: java, collections, hashset, linkedhashset

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

will not retain order obviously

```
Set<String> linkedHastSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

while reading elements from the above set it should retain order but in some times it does not ? am I wrong in my observation or I am missing something ?

Comment: What is the quote that makes you think it does not retain order?

Comment: Use a [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html), it provides: insertion order, thread-safety, no dublicates, safe iteration while looping

Comment: According to the javadoc, it does retain the order. Can you show an example where it does not?

Comment: Show us an example where order isn't retained

Comment: @ all I was wrong in my obersvation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only LinkedHashSet guarantees predictable order

From jdoc:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadoc for `LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is reasonably clear:

> the iteration ordering ... is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

Answer (score 0):

> and should be unique

A [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) implementation contains no duplicate elements, as explained in more detail in the Javadoc.

> java collection to retain order

What do you mean by "order"?

## Insertion-order: `LinkedHashSet`

If you mean tracking the order in which the objects were originally added to the set, use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

```
Set< String > colors = new LinkedHashSet<> () ;
String peachPuff = "PeachPuff" ;
colors.add( "CornflowerBlue" ) ;
colors.add( peachPuff ) ;
colors.add( "DarkSlateGray" ) ;
colors.add( peachPuff ) ; // Adding again. Original insertion order maintained.
```

Run [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RfVBNj). Notice how `peachPuff` object remains in its original # 2 position despite being added to the set a second time.

```
System.out.println( "colors.toString(): " + colors ) ;
```

> colors.toString(): [CornflowerBlue, PeachPuff, DarkSlateGray]

## Sorted-order: `TreeSet` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`

If you mean keeping the elements sorted by their content, use an implementation of [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (successor to [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html)).

The sorting is done either by:

- Calling the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) defined on any object implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.
- Using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation passed by you.

Two classes bundled with Java implement `NavigableSet` (and `SortedSet`): `TreeSet` & `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

### `TreeSet`

If you manipulating the set within a single thread, or only using the set across threads for reads only, use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Example:

```
Set< String > names = new TreeSet<> () ;
names.add( "Carol" ) ;
names.add( "Alice" ) ;
names.add( "Bob" ) ;
```

This will be reported in alphabetical order. See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RfVBNj).

> names.toString(): [Alice, Bob, Carol]

### `ConcurrentSkipListSet`

If manipulating the set across threads, [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) is an issue. Use [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) class.

You may want to learn about the [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) algorithm.

## Enum definition order: `EnumSet`

If you want to track a collection enum objects (see [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)) by the order in which they are defined on the enum, use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html). This class is highly optimized for enums, being very fast to execute and using very little memory.

Example: Track the weekend days from the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) ;
```

Despite our defining the set in wrong order, the [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) will iterate the items in the order defined on the `DayOfWeek` enum. That order is Monday-Sunday, so our `EnumSet` will iterate with Saturday reporting before Sunday.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RfVBNj).

> weekend.toString(): [SATURDAY, SUNDAY]